# Need help to Determine the Size a Subpanel

Tags: subpanel

The subpanel will have ac/spa/220v plug. 30+50+40=120 amp
Want would be the main breaker for amperage? 100 or 125 amperage?
I know the panel will be a 125 amp but I don't want a too big panel on the wall.
thanks for info

Comment: What are the actual minimum circuit ampacities/power ratings for the AC, spa, and thing you are plugging into the 220V socket?  Also, what would be the issue with a large panel on the wall at where you want to put it? (Photos of the proposed panel location would help.) Furthermore, can you post photos of your main panel as well please?

Comment: Actually you want the biggest panel you can get (in terms of number of spaces).  Someday you'll want to add circuits to this panel, and that will turn into a disaster if you scrimp on panel spaces today.  Anyway, panels are large because of cable turning radius rules.  That means more spaces doesn't make the panel much larger.  QO and CH breakers are only 3/4" tall, so 8 more breakers only adds 3" to an already 21" tall panel. And those extra 8 spaces will save you a whole lot of trouble later!